# Returning an instance of a class from IList<t>

Tags: c#, class, ilist

I would like to return the class Animal from foo. However, I would like to do so in a proper way so that future implementations of the code are easy to make. In other words, I do not want to use Obj.FirstOrDefault(). here is the code

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program Pro = new Program();
        Animal Cat = Pro.foo();
        Console.WriteLine(Cat.Name);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public Animal foo()
    {
        IList<Animal> Obj = new List<Animal>() { new Animal { Name = "Bob", ID = 1 } };
        Animal result = Obj.FirstOrDefault(); 
        return result;
    }
}
class Animal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I honestly don't understand what you're asking. What are you trying to achieve, and why don't you want to use the Enumerable methods to achieve it?

Comment: What is the purpose of the list.. Seems Redundant.

Just do

return new Animal { Name = "Bob", ID = 1 };

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to return Animal without FirstOrDefault(). You could prefix FirstOrDefault() with .Where(a => a.CatName = "Fido")